# SQL not working on c# but working in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql

Update should be updating the data in the confirm table with the given parameters. However no input gets updated/inputted despite there being no errors.
When the exact same query is inputted into the SQL Server Management Studio there is no errors and the rows are updated.

Why is the table not being updated?

There are 3 columns in the table - orderid (which is passed from another table) and then staffid and confirmed which should both be NULL - and are - until the rows are updated. orderid = int not null, staffid = int, confirmed = string.[confirm database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcalb.png)

The view is a left outer join, meaning that it shows the values that need to be update by the by.

[sql[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6nGg.png)

[database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlW2i.png)

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bPWZ.png)

How can this be fixed, its been like this for two days.

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data.SqlTypes;

    namespace ComicBookShop
    {
        public partial class orders_confirm : Form
        {

            public orders_confirm()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            //database details
            string connString = "Data Source = BLAH BLAH BLAH";


            private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Hide();
                ManagmentMain fm = new ManagmentMain();
                fm.Show();
            }

            private void orders_confirm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM staff_view", con))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                            {
                                sda.Fill(dt);

                                //Set AutoGenerateColumns False
                                dataGridView5.AutoGenerateColumns = true;


                                dataGridView5.DataSource = dt;

                            }
                        }
                    }


                    con.Close();
                }

            }
            private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (txtConfirmed.Text == "" || txtorder.Text == "" || txtstaff.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please fill textboxes");
                    return;
                }
                //database details
                string connString = "Data Source = aak; Initial Catalog = aa; User ID = aa; Password = aa";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            con.Open();
                            command.CommandText = "Update dbo.confirm set staffid=@staffid, confirmed=@confirmed where orderid =@orderid";

                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderid", txtorder.Text);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffid", txtstaff.Text);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@confirmed", txtConfirmed.Text);

                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            con.Close();
                            MessageBox.Show("Updated");

                        }

                        catch (SqlException ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

this is the part of the code where the data should be inserted

```
 private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (txtConfirmed.Text == "" || txtorder.Text == "" || txtstaff.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please fill textboxes");
                    return;
                }
                //database details
                string connString = "Data Source = aak; Initial Catalog = aa; User ID = aa; Password = aa";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            con.Open();
                            command.CommandText = "Update dbo.confirm set staffid=@staffid, confirmed=@confirmed where orderid =@orderid";

                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderid", txtorder.Text);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffid", txtstaff.Text);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@confirmed", txtConfirmed.Text);

                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            con.Close();
                            MessageBox.Show("Updated");

                        }

                        catch (SqlException ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What's the type of column `orderid`?

Comment: When you debug, what specifically happens?  What are the runtime values?  What are the *types* of the columns involved?  Note that `.AddWithValue()` is known to have potential problems with inferring types: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: You say orderid aand staffid are int but you set them with string values

Comment: updated post, below is what is shown when debugger is run and orderid is an int

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have highlighted the code that is the problem and by reading the post its fairly obviously that it is 1. within the btnupdate and 2. to do with the update statement - of which there is only 1.

Comment: why do you have "using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())" - later you set the datagridview source to point at that datatable, then it's thrown away at the end of the using() - so what does your datasource point to after that???  Learn how to use using(), and where NOT to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting parameters with their corresponding data types:

```
 command.Parameters.Add("orderid", SqlDbType.Int);
 command.Parameters["orderid"].Value = int.Parse(txtorder.Text);
```

Do the same for `staffid`.

I think the issue is you are passing `string` where `int` is expected.

Comment: I have added this in and still not working. This enables me to update the fields where there is already values in it, but the one that have NULL due to the data not been inserted yet, it does nothing. EDIT - before i could edit the details with values already inputted as well

Comment: When you say the values are not updated, are you talking about the form or the database itself? Have you browsed the database directly to verify that the rows are not updated?

Comment: I also noticed your code sample has two connections for some reason.

Comment: Im taking about the database itself, I have viewed the database directly and the rows are not displayed and even if I had not when re-opening the form, the datagridview is selecting from the database so it would have updated on to that